# Add custom request headers in NSwag

Tags: nswag

Some of my controllers require custom headers to be defined in a valid request.
The only way I know so far to add headers is to explicitly define a `[FromHeader(Name = "X-Custom-Data")]` parameter in my action methods.

I however have a middleware that runs before the action method is invoked and the headers are evaluated in this middleware. Thus I don't really need the header's value in the action itself.

What I'm looking for now is a way to let the swagger generator know that a custom header is needed for this request without having to specify those as method parameters.

As I wasn't able to find any attributes like `[SwaggerResponse]` but for headers I wanted to ask you guys if you know any solution to this.

Answer (score 1):

You can add them with a custom operation or document processor:

https://blog.rsuter.com/nswag-tutorial-implement-a-custom-operation-processor-to-define-redoc-code-samples/

Comment: I have followed this tutorial through and although I can see the custom header in the JSON output file, it doesn't show in redoc/swagger or the nswag.json config file